# Do all of the Hughes brothers' movies have religion references?

Tags: reference, analysis

I've seen so far: Menace II Society (1993) and The Book of Eli (2010) by Hughes brothers. Both of the movies have strong references to religion. In case of Menace II Society it's Christianity and Islam, in case of The Book of Eli it's only the Christianity (I would even argue, that those references are very important for understanding the whole movie).

Do all of the Hughes brothers' movies have religion references?

Answer (score 1):

[Dead Presidents](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112819/) doesn't contain strong religious references.  It deals with a heist as well as social and civil problems Black Americans have faced.  That said, they've produced two movies and five episodes of a Television series called Touching Evil.  They were executive producers on From Hell, and produced two documentaries.  They've pretty much directed everything they produced.  So, of the 4 movies they produced/directed, one had no religious overtones.